# How to specify the same datatype for all (over 20.000) columns in meta for dask?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, dask

I have a user-defined function `tmp_func` and a dask dataframe `df`. I would like to apply this function on each group of `df`.

```
def tmp_func(s_df):
    ...
    return(s_df)

result = df.groupby('id').apply(tmp_func, meta = meta)
result = result.compute(scheduler = 'processes')
```

It is [recommended](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) to specify the dtypes of columns of dataframe returned by `tmp_func`. In my case, the resulting dataframe from `tmp_func` has over 20.000 columns which contain only natural numbers. So I think `np.int8` is the datatype.

Is there anyway to specify that all columns have the same datatype `np.int8`? It would be a nightmare to specify it by a dictionary with over 20.000 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a dict-comprehension

```
result = df.groupby('id').apply(tmp_func, meta = {col: np.int8 for col in df.columns)}
```